# URL rewrite in htaccess results is missing CSS and images

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to remove a specific thing from my URL. Here I give a page name `user.php` and get it using `$_GET['url']` then make it array using PHP `explode()` method.

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?url=user
```

I need to remove the `index.php?url=` like this,

```
https://www.example.com/user
```

Now I already use this code in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

Almost everything was fine the `user.php` page was loaded perfectly. But when I was given a slash to my URL it stops showing CSS or other IMG directories. But when I delete the `.htaccess` file it works fine in this URL:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?url=user/anonymous
```

But not works in this URL when I assign the `.htaccess` rules.

```
https://www.example.com/user/anonymous
```

Why my all stylesheet and other directory is not working perfectly?

Comment: slash turns your url into a directory, so you need to use `request_uri` `https://www.example.com/index.php?url=user/anonymous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
> ```

I think you have a couple of glaring typos(?) in your question that make this directive completely invalid... you are missing a `RewriteRule` *pattern*, so this won't actually match anything and the erroneous *space* in the flags argument is syntactically invalid, resulting in a 500 Internal Server Error response?!

The `RewriteRule` directive should be written like:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`^([\w/-]+)$` matches a URL-path containing any of the characters: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore), `/` (slash) and `-` (hyphen). I've excluded the dot, which is naturally part of real filenames.

You should also ensure that MultiViews is disabled, so that mod_negotiation doesn't rewrite the request before `mod_rwrite` - since your "extensionless" requests appear to map directly to filenames. eg. `/user` maps to `/user.php`. Place the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

> But when I was given a slash to my URL it stops showing CSS or other IMG directories.

This isn't a problem with `.htaccess`, but is caused by using *relative* client-side URLs to your static resources. When you request the URL `/user/anonymous` then the *browser* will resolve any relative URLs *relative* to `/user/anonymous` (not the document root - which is probably what you are expecting). If you have a relative URL to `css/styles.css` then the *browser* is naturally going to resolve this to `/user/css/styles.css` - which probably doesn't exist (and is likely getting rewritten to `index.php` - but that isn't the issue - the fact that it doesn't exist is the issue).

If you look at the network traffic (HTTP requests) in the browser, it should give you a clue as to what's going on.

You need to change your client-side URLs to use either root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute (scheme + hostname) URLs to fix this issue.

See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack that explains this further:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
#main user page
RewriteRule ^user$ index.php?url=user [L]
#user detail page
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: have you removed all the 3 **RewriteCond** conditions from your old htaccess file?

Comment: just replace the htaccess code as above also make sure you have enabled the mod_rewrite module.