# htaccess rewrite rule not working after migrating to php 8

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am facing issue with url rewrite rules after migrating to PHP 8 from PHP 7.

On top of htaccess I am having below code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /baba/
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/baba/404.php
```

1. Search pages:-

This is working fine if I am using only below rule:-

```
   RewriteRule ^s/([\w-]+)/(.*)$ search.php?feq=$1&key=$2 [QSA,L]
```

But If I am adding more rules like below then these pages gives 404.

```
   RewriteRule ^s/([\w-]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ search.php?feq=$1&city=$2&key=$3 [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^s/([\w-]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ search.php?feq=$1&pro=$2&city=$3&key=$4 [QSA,L]
```

2. Landing pages:-

This is working fine if I am using only below rule:-

```
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ land.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But If I am adding more rules like below then css and images stops loading on other pages and these pages gives 404.

```
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ land.php?name=$1&pro=$2&city=$3 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.*)$ land.php?name=$1&key=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.*)/(.*) land.php?name=$1&city=$2&key=$3 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ land.php?name=$1&pro=$2&city=$3&key=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: To be clear, you aren't adding any rules, these rules already existed in your previous system, right?

Comment: You should state what URLs you are requesting and how these are expected to be handled.

Comment: I don't see how upgrading your PHP version would affect how Apache reads the htaccess-files?

Comment: You may need to rearrange your rules. Both #1 and #2 might match #3 and #4. Try ordering them by longest to shortest.

Comment: It also looks like #1 and #3 would match the exact same path, so only one would apply.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with PHP version - your rules obviously conflict...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^s/([\w-]+)/(.*)$ search.php?feq=$1&key=$2 [QSA,L]
> ```
>
> But If I am adding more rules like below then these pages gives 404.
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^s/([\w-]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ search.php?feq=$1&city=$2&key=$3 [QSA,L]
> RewriteRule ^s/([\w-]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ search.php?feq=$1&pro=$2&city=$3&key=$4 [QSA,L]
> ```

Because the regex in the first rule is too general (it matches `/s/foo/<anything>`), if you simply add the 2nd two rules then the first rule will still catch all requests and rewrite to `search.php?feq=foo&key=<anything>` regardless of the number of path segments. You need to be more specific with the regex. For example, only match whole path segments, not literally *anything*:

```
RewriteRule ^s/([\w-]+)/([^/]*)$ search.php?feq=$1&key=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^s/([\w-]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)$ search.php?feq=$1&city=$2&key=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^s/([\w-]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)$ search.php?feq=$1&pro=$2&city=$3&key=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Note the `[^/]` (anything except `/`) instead of `.` (anything). Also the use of `+` (1 or more) in the mandatory path segments.

As with your original rule, the `key` URL parameter (ie. the 2nd path segment in the first rule and last path segment in subsequent rules) is *optional*. Is that intentional?

If you know the characters that are permitted in these URL parameters then these should be indicated in the regex to further restrict the URLs that would otherwise be (incorrectly) rewritten.

You could also have reversed the order of the directives to solve the immediate problem, but that is only a part solution as your regex would still be far too generic.

> But If I am adding more rules like below then css and images stops loading on other pages and these pages gives 404.

As above. But failure to CSS and images is likely due to using relative URL-paths to these resources in your client-side HTML. You are rewriting the request from differing path depths, so you must use root-relative (or absolute) URLs to your static resources. Relative URLs are naturally resolved (by the browser) relative to the URL in the browser address bar.

(As a workaround you can set the `base` element in the `head` section to indicate the base URL-path that all relative URLs are *relative* to, but this is not without its caveats.)

Further reading regarding missing assets:

- [URL rewrite in htaccess results is missing CSS and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014915/url-rewrite-in-htaccess-results-is-missing-css-and-images)
- [404 not found - broken links to CSS, images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737411/404-not-found-broken-links-to-css-images)
- [JS and CSS Rendering Issues After .htaccess File URL Rewrite Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563233/js-and-css-rendering-issues-after-htaccess-file-url-rewrite-rule)

Note also that your "landing page" rules must come *after* the "search page" rules otherwise these will also conflict. Again, this conflict can be avoided by making the regex more specific. For example, by making the first path segment (value of the `name` URL parameter) in the "landing pages" be 2 or more characters, not 1 or more, so to avoid conflicting with `/s/` (in "search").

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/baba/404.php
> ```

This triggers a 302 (temporary) redirect to your 404 error document (which masks the 404 response and URL that actually triggered the 404). This is usually undesirable, unless you have very specific requirements. You should normally use a root-relative URL-path here. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /baba/404.php
```

`/baba/404.php` is then served via an internal subrequest and the error document itself is not exposed to the end user.

If you resorted to using a "redirect" as a way to workaround an issue with missing assets then see the above point about not using relative URLs in your HTML source.

Comment: thanks for reply. I will check with your solution.

Comment: I just reorder rules and this start working.